# FullCalander, Angular 17 type errors

Tags: fullcalendar-6

I'm a bit stuck. I'm attempting to use FullCalander 6.1.11 with Angular 17. I'm using node 18.18.2.

I'm receiving several type errors on ng serve compiles. The imports in bold are not found. If I add '/' to /core/, this quiets this compile error. Why would this happen?

import { DatePointApi, **ViewApi**, EventApi, **EventChangeArg**, Duration, **EventDropArg**, PluginDef } from '@fullcalendar/core';

Comment: Add this error to the bunch from the private-types.d.ts file : TS2305: Module '"@fullcalendar/core"' has no exported member 'CalendarOptions'.